# Why does img src not work in forums?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, src

I use mostly Chrome.

When I publish some work in sites as DeviantArt, Blogger, Flickr I am unable to show an image instead of a link or just show the image, it is really annoying, since I tried a lot of stuff to solve the issue. I use:

```
<img src="https://VALID LINK" >

<a href="https://VALID WEBSITE">< img src="https://VALID BANNER on another 
website"/></a>

<a href="URL Address"><img src="Image URL address" alt="Name of Image" /></a>
```

Only shows https://website address in blue to be clicked and ordinary code

```
<a href="URL Address">Name of Link</a>
```

That code works perfectly

I want that a clickable image is shown, which direct you after you click it to the desired website. Why does code not work? Is it because of some protection or what?

[I use code as instructed in deviant art support or in most other sites](https://www.deviantartsupport.com/en/article/how-do-i-link-to-other-deviants-deviations-or-pages#html-image-linking)

Comment: remove space between < and img

Comment: Already done that a lot of times before, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Click on icon after run and check its working fine

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Stackoverflow_icon.png" 
alt="Name of Image" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not working.

[Code1](https://ibb.co/dsp8v7)

[Result of a code, image not shown](https://ibb.co/fuVFa7)